# Is there a way to shorten command line commands to open Python scripts?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I'd like to know if there is a way to shorten what must be written on the `cmd.exe` command line to run Python programs. As it is, I have a program called `Calculator.py` and if I wanted to run that I would have to write:

```
python.exe C:\Users\user_name\restofdirectory\Calculator.py
```

Basically I want to know if I could make the 'Python' folder on my computer default so I could just type `python.exe Calculator.py` or some other similarly short way of doing it so I didn't have to type the whole directory.

Comment: If you go into the directory where the script is, you should be able to just type the command: python Calculator.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a cmd.exe shortcut somewhere handy (Desktop or whatever). Right Click, select properties. Under the Shortcut tab you'll have a "Start In" field. It'll be default to wherever your cmd.exe normally opens. But you can change it to any path you want (So set it to your python development folder)-- then opening that shortcut will always start cmd.exe in the python folder.

You don't need to type **python.exe file.py** -- 
Just type: **python file.py**

So in short, you'd click that shortcut and type **python file.py** and you are done.

If you have specific scripts you want to run frequently, you can create a cmd.exe shortcut for each one. Set the Start In path to their folder. Then update the link to cmd.exe like this:

```
c:\path\to\cmd.exe /k python file.py
```

That will open a cmd prompt and automatically run that specific script

Comment: Thanks! But how do I open files with multiple word names -- for example, Prime Generator.py?

Comment: You are much better off making single word names such as prime_generator.py -- If you REALLY must use a two word name, do it this way: python 'Prime Generator.py' with single quotes.

Comment: On Windows you can probably just type **file.py**

Comment: martineau may be correct, I'm on a Linux machine at the moment and can't test. On that note, my single quotes comment was based on BASH. In windows you might have to do double quotes around the file name

Comment: Add `C:\Users\user_name\restofdirectory` to the `PATH` environment variable, and you can run `file.py`. If you add `.PY` to the `PATHEXT` environment variable, then you can simply run `file`. In PowerShell adding the extension to `PATHEXT` is also required to even run `file.py` since, unlike the cmd shell, it only searches `PATH` for files that have an extension that's listed in `PATHEXT`. (It's really arrogant of PowerShell to not preserve the semantics of an environment variable that's been in use for over 20 years.)

Comment: Turns out using @Lost 's method I can just type file.py.

Comment: @Mathime one thing I forgot. If you have some scripts you run frequently, you can make additional command prompt short cuts. You set their "start in" field to where the file is, and a field or two above that where it has the path to cmd.exe you adjust it to c:\path\to\cmd.exe /k python file.py  <---Basically makes a shortcut to run a specific file so you double click to launch (but requires new shortcut for each file using that method). Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can cd into the folder first.

Answer (score 0):

If python is in your default path you can create a folder and put all your python scripts in it. Then `cd` into that folder and type `python Calculator.py`. To test if python is in your path simply open up a cmd and type `cd \` (which in your case should change your working directory to `C:\`) then type python. If you get an error saying the command python cannot be found then you have to add python to your path. Other wise you should be able to run `cd C:\Users\user_name\restofdirectory\` and then execute the script `python Calculator.py`

Answer (score 0):

create an environment variable, say, PyPath = C:\Users\user_name\restofdirectory

then your line would be:

```
python.exe %PyPath%\Calculator.py
```

or you just cd to C:\Users\user_name\restofdirectory, and run

```
python.exe Calculator.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Python to your path:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27\bin
```

then you can call python like this:

```
python myapp.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) (comes with Python 3.3+) installed, then it gets even easier. You just need to put shebang in your code:

```
#! python
```

The first time you run your code, Windows will pop up a dialog and ask you what program to use to run the script. The Python Launcher should be listed. Just choose that and away you go.  Here's a fun little script from the page I linked earlier:

```
#! python
import sys
sys.stdout.write("hello from Python %s\n" % (sys.version,))
```

Once my Windows 7 box had the launcher installed and I told it what program to run, I could just call my script from cmd.exe like this:

```
my_script.py
```

Note: If you have a version of Python older than 3.3, you can download the installer [here](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher/downloads)